# Intelligent Username SQL Database Search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So a very common feature in many applications is searching for usernames in the database. Common suggestions are using a LIKE with %searchname%, however the problem with this method is that it will return the results in no particular order, not placing more relevant results above less relevant ones.

For example, if my table contains Bob, Hobobo, Tabob and Bobert, the search for "bob" will return all of them, but it will potentially put Tabob and Hobobo at the top of the results.

I was thinking something along the lines of doing a LIKE searchname%, and concatenating it with the LIKE %searchname% table and then applying UNIQUE to it, but I was wondering if anyone had a more powerful, less search intensive(ideally 1 query) solution for properly organizing the results with more relevant ones on top.

This seems like a simple enough issue, but I haven't actually seen a nice clean solution for it.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: Oh nice! Is there an equivalent in other languages(I know this question said MySQL), just for curiosity's sake.